# How do I give JSON raw data when there is a bad request?

Tags: java, jpa

A table entity of Account containing username and userEmail and phone number and no repetition is allowed. What I did is I passed a query every time when an API that creates account is called. That query basically checks if the username, email or phone number already exist or not and throws a validationException if it exists.

What I want to do is to give raw JSON data when a bad request is made. How do I achieve that?

edit 1. I am using PlayFrameWork, raw JSON data means as in `return ok(Json.tojson()object);`

Comment: That Json data is the existing account

Comment: what do you mean by raw JSON?

Comment: @pankajgulia Note: giving back the full information about an existing account is a BAD idea. Why would you tell a potential new user about the phone number of an existing user? If at all, return a message that says "user name (or email or phone) is already taken". Don't create APIs that disclose information that doesn't need to be disclosed!

Comment: @GhostCat its just practice exercise later i will check on the level of information to be released for now just focus is on how?

Comment: @HariHaravelan raw JSOn as in return ok(Json.tojson(object))

Comment: Please dont give such information in comments. Always update your question instead. And note: so you are using some framework method `ok()` that probably emits a HTTP 200 OKAY response with the given response body. Most likely, that framework has OTHER methods that allow you to emit say a 409 CONFLICT ... with some response body.